# How do I add more variants or custom packages to debootstrap?

Tags: chroot, debootstrap

I have a set of packages that I wish to install along-side the minibase variant in debootstrap. I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to customize variants so that more than just the base is installed in a chroot when debootstrap is run. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's pretty easy to add your own variant with additional custom packages to *debootstrap*.

The *debootstrap* configuration/runtime scripts are located in `/usr/share/debootstrap/scripts`. Let's create an `allmybase` variant which includes everything in `minbase` along with the packages `htop` and `traceroute`.

1. Open `/usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/precise` in your editor.

   - Note that this, along with many Ubuntu releases, is a symbolic link to `/usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/gutsy`; if you want to affect only a specific release, break the link and make it a copy of the *gutsy* script instead.
2. Around line 22, find the line beginning with `variants` and add your custom variant at the end:

   ```
   variants - buildd fakechroot minbase allmybase
   ```
3. Find the `work_out_debs()` function around line 34, and look at the default settings for the `base` variable for your "base" variant (here, `minbase`):

   ```
       elif doing_variant fakechroot || doing_variant minbase; then
               base="apt"
   ```
4. Append your own variant with custom packages at the end of the function:

   ```
       elif doing_variant allmybase; then
               base="apt htop traceroute"
   ```
5. Save, exit, and test it out with the `--print-debs` "simulation" flag, e.g.

   ```
   sudo debootstrap --print-debs --variant=allmybase precise /tmp/prec-chroot
   ```

   - In this example, the output will show that the `htop` and `traceroute` packages will be included in the *allmybase* chroot.

Comment: Wow, I guess this seems almost as dirty as just installing a variant and mounting the chroot + apt-get. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Well, a little pain once will gain you a lot if you install the same variant repeatedly ;)

Comment: Maybe that option did not exist at the time of the question, but the same effect can be achieved with `debootstrap --include=htop,traceroute` without any modifications to debootstrap scripts.