# Install ubuntu server edition into a chroot

Tags: server, chroot

Using a `chroot` with `debootstrap` you can install, for example, Ubuntu 14.04 with

```
sudo debootstrap trusty /var/chroot/trusty http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

This will, as I understand, install a basic 14.04 installation. Is there any way to install Ubuntu 14.04 Server edition into the chrooted environment?

For an answer I'd either like that it's not possible, or how to do it - not "Install 14.04 and remove things you don't need"

Comment: Technically, there is no *server* edition. The Ubuntu server installation asks you to pick the packages/tasks you want to install. Therefore the `debootstrap` command you used is a fair approximation of a server installation with no additional packages installed. 
If you do want to install additional packages as part of `debootstrap` instead of after the bootstrap, you can check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/168158/how-do-i-add-more-variants-or-custom-packages-to-debootstrap. I'd vote to close as a dupe, but a question with a bounty can't be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Debootstrap installs a very, very basic system, only the absolutely essential packages. There is virtually nothing to be removed and is certainely not a full installation of Ubuntu. So just install all the software you want to use there.